# Install Mongodb on windows 7 - 64 bit

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb and not getting how to install it since i dint find videos or any helpful resources to achieve the same. Please help me for installing mongodb on windows 7 with the exact steps. I tried downloading recent version of mongodb from the site and its unsuccessful. Thanks in adcance.

Regards,

Vijay

Comment: not a programming question. Maybe, you ask this in superuser.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the info. can you please guide me the route map for the same.

Comment: join the Superuser community here: http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 13):

Steps:

1. Download MongoDB this link [link](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center).
2. Review MongoDB folder.
   In MongoDB, it contains only executable files 10 Plus(exe) in the bin folder. This is true, and That are the required files to MongoDB, it's really hard to believe for a developer like me Who eats from a relation database background.

   ```
   path:- Files under $MongoDB/bin folder
   ```
3. Configuration File
   Create a MongoDB config file, it’s just a text file, for example `C:\mongodb\mongo.config`:

   ```
   #store data here
   dbpath=C:\mongodb\data

   \\all output go here
   logpath=C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log

   \\log read and write operations
   diaglog=3
   ```
4. Run MongoDB server
   Use `mongod.exe --config C:\mongodb\mongo.config` to start MongoDB server.

   ```
   C:\mongodb\bin>mongod --config C:\mongodb\mongo.config
   ```

   All output going to: `C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log`
5. Connect to MongoDB
   Uses mongo.exe to connect to the started MongoDB server.

   C:\mongodb\bin>mongo
   MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
   connecting to: test

   > //mongodb shell
6. MongoDB as Windows Service
   Add MongoDB as Windows Service, so that MongoDB will start automatically following each system restart.
   Install as Windows Service with `--install`.

   ```
   C:\mongodb\bin> mongod --config C:\mongodb\mongo.config --install
   ```

   A Windows service named “MongoDB” is created.

   To start MongoDB Service:

   ```
   net start MongoDB
   ```

   To stop MongoDB Service

   ```
   net stop MongoDB
   ```

   To remove MongoDB Service

   ```
   C:\mongodb\bin>mongod --remove
   ```

   [Reference Link Install Mongodb](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows/)

Comment: I have a question here if somebody can help me. When i go to the site it shows only windows 2008 R2 options and when i go to "All version Binaries", I do not see zip for win 64. I want to download the zip folder of MongoDB on Windows 10. Can somebody please help me direct to the link ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The installers for  2008 Server should also work for windows 7 64 Bit.     If you got to the **mongoDB install guide** [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#requirements]  it states under requirtements: _Determine which MongoDB build you need.

The following MongoDB builds are available for Windows:

MongoDB for Windows 64-bit runs only on Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7 64-bit, and newer versions of Windows._

Answer (score 2):

For mongoDB 4.x, I got installation hung up several times in "wait for a few minutes..."
I changed to v3.2.21-1 as recommended from searching the answer from web. It installed very quick and fast as I installed one year ago.

Answer (score 1):

1. firstly you downloaded  mongodb from here : https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community
2. you unzip the folder in your directory example `C:\..\MongoDB`
3. you open the command prompt ( demarrer>Invite commande)
4. you go to your folder where the bin is and you write this on your command prompt : `cd c:\..\mongodb\bin`
5. then you have to specifies the directory where you want to put the data, you can create a folder called : MongoData, and you whrite on your command prompt: `Mongod --dbpath C:\..\MongoData`

Answer (score 0):

Download the version 4.0.22 from [here](https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.22-signed.msi)

And follow steps from [Use this tutorial to install MongoDB 5.0 Community Edition on Windows using the default installation wizard](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

All the best!!!

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information from the link(s) provided in the answer itself. This helps to ensure your answer doesn't become invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**use mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.22-signed** for Windows7 64 bit