# MongoDB won't install on Windows 7 machine

Tags: mongodb

I have tried to install the current version of MongoDB, namely, mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.10-signed.msi, on two different Windows 7 installations, and in both cases it got about 2/3 of the way through the install and then hung and wouldn't go any further.  Both installations are on older PCs that don't support Windows 10.

Would this be the issue?  That is, does this version of MongoDB use something that only works on machines that support Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this question that was previously asked?

[Install Mongodb on windows 7 - 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130239/install-mongodb-on-windows-7-64-bit)

If you scroll to the bottom you will find an answer that deals specifically with MongoDB v4 hanging on Windows 7 _ and how this issue was resolved

Comment: Thanks, Maik.  I take this to mean that the current version of MongoDB doesn't work on Windows 7.  They (Mongo) should say this. It would save a lot  of grief.

Comment: I searched the Mongo site for version details too @Frogpants  _ Bit surprised not to find anything useful in that regard _ Hopefully falling back to an earlier version will mean you can install to your Win7 machines _ Good Luck